# In maariv for 2nd night Shavuos לא תגנוב means “do not steal” and not “do not kidnap.” Why?

Tags: song-poetry, maariv, shavuos

[Rashi points out](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920/showrashi/true) in Parshas Kodoshim 19(11) (and elsewhere) that the commandment “לא תגנוב” in the Ten Commandments refers to kidnapping. The poet in the additions to the [evening service for the second night of Shavuos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43447&st=&pgnum=230&hilite=) writes, “לא תגנוב - קבוצות זהב חשוקות Do not steal – bundles of desirable gold. Why is that?

Comment: He's being poetic?

Comment: As far as drush, this means [kidnapping](http://dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/points/sn-ps-086.htm), but some interpret the p'shat as including stealing, too (e.g. Ibn Ezra and S'forno).

Comment: @Fred, that sounds like an answer. Why don't you post it as one, perhaps after fleshing it out?

Answer (score 7):

That comment of Rash"i is quoting from the *G'mara* ([*Sanhedrin* 86](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A4%D7%95_%D7%90)), which derives that [although the words plainly mean "do not steal"] based on the hermeneutic device called *davar halamed me'inyano*. The context of capital crimes in which "*lo signov*" appears implies that it too must be the capital crime of kidnapping. The meaning of the *pasuk* is therefore slightly different (i.e. more specified) than the meaning of the words de(or re)contextualized. The verb ג.נ.ב is certainly still available (especially to a poet) for its broader meaning of "steal".

In fact, the same *g'mara* that derives the specification of "*lo signov*" meaning "do not kidnap" derives the specification of the almost identical *pasuk* "*lo signovu*" meaning "do not steal [things]".

Comment: As I mentioned above, this is not simply from context, it is from the *sh'losh esrei middos shehaTorah nidreshes bahen*. That's why, on a p'shat level, the Ibn Ezra and S'forno on Parshas Yisro (20:13) maintained that this very pasuk includes the prohibition against regular stealing, kidnapping, and *g'neivas da'as*.

Comment: @Fred Specifically, it is from the _mida_ of _davar halamed me'inyano_, which is what I meant by the English shorthand "context". I will edit it in, but is that inaccurate?

Comment: Not inaccurate, but it might have given the wrong impression considering that you wrote, "*The verb ג.נ.ב is certainly still available (especially to a poet) for its broader meaning of "steal"*," which might be understood to mean that that interpretation can not be the *p'shat* in this verse.