# The Ear That Heard "Don't Steal"

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, slave-serve-eved-avadim, mishpatim, mechilta

[Rashi to Exodus 21:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9882/showrashi/true#v6) quotes the [Mechilta](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40607&st=&pgnum=183&hilite=) which connects the drilling of the ear of the slave to hearing "don't steal" at Sinai. The obvious question asked by the Moshav Z'keinim (there) is that Rashi and the Mechilta themselves write that this refers not to theft but to kidnapping ([Rashi commentary to Exodus 20:13](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9881/showrashi/true#v13); Mechilta [there](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40607&st=&pgnum=159&hilite=) and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40607&st=&pgnum=194&hilite=))!

Comment: But according to Rav Saadia that includes stealing of properties.

Comment: Does the Moshav Z'keinim give an answer?

Comment: Exegetically, chazal say this refers to kidnapping, but the *p'shat* reading also includes regular theft.

Comment: @user6591 which R. Saadya Gaon?

Comment: @Ypnypn  ואע״ג דלא תגנוב מדבר בגונב נפשות דוקא מדבר הלמד מעניינו, ואותו גנב אינו נרצע, והיה לו להביא מלא תגנובו (ויקרא י״ט י״א) שכתוב בגונב ממון. וי״ל משום דכל שם גניבה אחת היא ולא דק בלישניה, ולישנא קלילא נקט.

Comment: @mevaqesh That all 613 mitzvos are included in the Aseres HaDibros.

Comment: @user6591 I thought that too, especially as Rashi mentions it, but i'm not thrilled with the answer.

Comment: You can also say that "kidnapping" means making a slave of someone and the ear that heard that someone should not make a slave of another went and made a slave of himself. Since I do not have a source for this, I cannot make it an answer. I will check Rav Hirsch when I can.

Comment: @sabbahillel that was my preferred answer, I wanted to know of anyone had a source for it, (although not wanting to stifle creative effort, I didn't write it in the question)

Comment: @Fred do you have a source for this? i;m pretty sure that halachically the azhara, formal prohibition, is from "lo signovu"

Comment: @mevaqesh See, for example, S'forno (*Sh'mos* 20:13): לא תגנוב. בכלל גנבה גנבת נפשות וגנבת ממון וגנבת דעת הבריות, אף על פי שעקר האזהרה על גנבת נפשות

Comment: @Fred but i'm pretty sure that Sforno differs from the Gemara (which is fine) but Rashi is quoting Chazal.

Comment: @mevaqesh (Also see [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16174/in-maariv-for-2nd-night-shavuos-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91-means-do-not-steal-and-not-do-not-ki#comment33594_16174)). Anyway, Rashi is just quoting Chazal in both places. Why not say that he is quoting Chazal from an exegetical standpoint in 20:13 and from a *p'shat* (or even homiletical) standpoint in 21:6?

Comment: Because I assume that the Mechilta agreed with the ruling of the Gemara which I believe is that "lo signov" doesnt "also include" kidnapping, it only includes it, and a thief instead violates lo signovu. If so, the Mechilta (not Rashi) is difficult.

Comment: @mevaqesh You are right... from the standpoint *d'rash* and the halachic source for the *lav*. It's a דבר הלמד מעניינו. But that doesn't necessarily speak to the *p'shat* or a homiletical interpretation.

Comment: So - What's your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently although the Mechilta understood the prohibition to be kidnapping it still recognizes the literal meaning of theft. This is implied by [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40607&st=%25u05DC%25u05D0+%25u05EA%25u05D2%25u05E0%25u05D5%25u05D1&pgnum=79&hilite=) mechilta and also somewhat implied by [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40607&st=%25u05DC%25u05D0%20%25u05EA%25u05D2%25u05E0%25u05D5%25u05D1&pgnum=148&hilite=) mechilta.

Comment: I like this answer better than other proposed answers because rather than conjecture, it is based on internal evidence from the Mechilta.

Comment: You’ve answered for the Mechilta, but how do you answer Rashi?